# Not able to connect to all DID numbers in pri

Tags: centos, asterisk, voip, configure, ivr

I have 2 DAHDI card and 2 pri in my centos 6 .One of the pri is working fine means I can call through all DIDs and dialplan works fine but in other pri only some of the DID active means starting 10 DIDs can receive the calls and when I call the other DIDs after 10th DID a message is played `All channels are busy` with no info in cli.

Also I am not able to set callerid in **.call** file for second pri.

I cant seem to figure out whether this problem is with provider or configuration mistake.

**system.conf**

```
# Span 1: WCT1/0 "Wildcard TE121 Card 0" (MASTER) CCS/HDB3/CRC4 ClockSource 
span=1,1,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4
# termtype: te
bchan=1-15,17-31
dchan=16
echocanceller=mg2,1-15,17-31

# Span 2: WCT1/1 "Wildcard TE121 Card 1" 
span=2,2,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4
# termtype: te
bchan=32-46,48-62
dchan=47
echocanceller=mg2,32-46,48-62

# Global data

loadzone    = us
defaultzone = us
```

**chan_dahdi.conf**

```
[channels]
context=from-pstn-old
usecallerid=yes
callwaiting=yes
echocancel=yes
echocancelwhenbridged=yes
rxgain=0.0
txgain=0.0
pridialplan=unknown
prilocaldialplan=unknown
switchtype=euroisdn
language = yes
relaxdtmf = yes
dtmfmode=auto
transfer=yes

;Span 1:
context=from-pstn
group=0
callgroup=1
pickupgroup=1
echocancel=yes
signalling=pri_cpe
channel => 1-15,17-31,32-46,48-62
context=default
usecallerid=yes
callerid=asreceived
hanguponpolarityswitch=yes
answeronpolarityswitch=yes
cidstart=polarity_IN
cidsignalling=dtmf
hidecallerid=no
callwaiting=yes
usecallingpres=yes
callwaitingcallerid=yes
threewaycalling=yes
transfer=yes
canpark=yes
cancallforward=yes
callreturn=yes
echocancel=yes
echocancelwhenbridged=yes
relaxdtmf=yes
rxgain=0.0
txgain=0.0
group=1
callgroup=1
pickupgroup=1
immediate=no
useincomingcalleridondahditransfer=yes
busydetect=yes
busycount=2
```

output of `pri show spans`

```
nsg-static-98*CLI> pri show spans
PRI span 1/0: Up, Active
PRI span 2/0: Up, Active
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off hand I don't see anything wrong with your configuration.  I would suggest contacting the support organization for your PRI provider and trouble-shooting with them.